# Как сохранить svg в base64?

Tags: javascript, svg, maker.js

У меня строка содержащая `svg` тег(не нода). Как мне её сохранить в `base64`? Данную строку формирует [Maker.js](https://maker.js.org). Есть похожий вопрос [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450471/convert-inline-svg-to-base64-string), но там ноду передовать необходимо.

Результат в `html`:

```
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="-10 -10 220 220" style="padding : 10px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g id="svgGroup" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="9pt" stroke="green" stroke-width="0.5mm" fill="none" style="stroke:green;stroke-width:0.5mm;fill:none"><g id="0"><g id="trapeze"><line id="line1" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line1&quot;]" x1="0" y1="200" x2="200" y2="200" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></line><line id="line2" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line2&quot;]" x1="200" y1="200" x2="175" y2="0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></line><line id="line3" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line3&quot;]" x1="175" y1="0" x2="25" y2="0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></line><line id="line4" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line4&quot;]" x1="25" y1="0" x2="0" y2="200" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></line></g></g></g></svg>
```

Результат `Maker.js`:

```
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="-10 -10 220 220" style="padding : 10px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g id="svgGroup" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="9pt" stroke="green" stroke-width="0.5mm" fill="none" style="stroke:green;stroke-width:0.5mm;fill:none"><g id="0"><g id="trapeze"><line id="line1" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line1&quot;]" x1="0" y1="200" x2="200" y2="200" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><line id="line2" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line2&quot;]" x1="200" y1="200" x2="175" y2="0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><line id="line3" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line3&quot;]" x1="175" y1="0" x2="25" y2="0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><line id="line4" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line4&quot;]" x1="25" y1="0" x2="0" y2="200" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/></g></g></svg>
```

> Ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Маркера xml у тебя не хватает, а в остальном всё как всегда.

Comment: @Qwertiy,а по конкретнее)

Comment: лучше конечно было бы увидеть сразу результирующую svg

Comment: @StrangerintheQ подправил.

Comment: @doox911 смотрите ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно Вас понял, Вы ищите это:

```js
let svg = `<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="-10 -10 220 220" style="padding : 10px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g id="svgGroup" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="9pt" stroke="green" stroke-width="0.5mm" fill="none" style="stroke:green;stroke-width:0.5mm;fill:none"><g id="0"><g id="trapeze"><line id="line1" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line1&quot;]" x1="0" y1="200" x2="200" y2="200" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></line><line id="line2" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line2&quot;]" x1="200" y1="200" x2="175" y2="0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></line><line id="line3" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line3&quot;]" x1="175" y1="0" x2="25" y2="0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></line><line id="line4" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line4&quot;]" x1="25" y1="0" x2="0" y2="200" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></line></g></g></g></svg>`

img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(svg)
```

```html
<img id="img">
```

---

Еще есть похожий способ, который не требует заворачивания в `base64` а работает через `encodeURIComponent`

```js
let svg = `<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="-10 -10 220 220" style="padding : 10px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g id="svgGroup" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="9pt" stroke="green" stroke-width="0.5mm" fill="none" style="stroke:green;stroke-width:0.5mm;fill:none"><g id="0"><g id="trapeze"><line id="line1" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line1&quot;]" x1="0" y1="200" x2="200" y2="200" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></line><line id="line2" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line2&quot;]" x1="200" y1="200" x2="175" y2="0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></line><line id="line3" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line3&quot;]" x1="175" y1="0" x2="25" y2="0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></line><line id="line4" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line4&quot;]" x1="25" y1="0" x2="0" y2="200" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></line></g></g></g></svg>`

img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,'+ encodeURIComponent(svg)
```

```html
<img id="img">
```

---

> UPD

Вот фокус чтобы починить теги с самозакрытых на обычные, по крайней мере в хроме и лисе отработал

```js
let svg = `<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="-10 -10 220 220" style="padding : 10px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g id="svgGroup" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="9pt" stroke="green" stroke-width="0.5mm" fill="none" style="stroke:green;stroke-width:0.5mm;fill:none"><g id="0"><g id="trapeze"><line id="line1" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line1&quot;]" x1="0" y1="200" x2="200" y2="200" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><line id="line2" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line2&quot;]" x1="200" y1="200" x2="175" y2="0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><line id="line3" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line3&quot;]" x1="175" y1="0" x2="25" y2="0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/><line id="line4" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line4&quot;]" x1="25" y1="0" x2="0" y2="200" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/></g></g></svg>`

let div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = svg;

img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+ btoa(div.innerHTML)
```

```html
<img id="img">
```

Comment: Спасибо. Первый вариант пробовал, почему-то не отрабатывал)

Comment: `Maker.js` методом `makerjs.exporter.toSVG()` возвращает самозакрывающиеся теги, а броузеры перепарсивают на обычные теги. Например: `<line/>`  в  `<line></line>`.

Comment: Да) Метод ваш рабочий, но броузер ругается и не открывает.

Comment: Конечно, костльненько)

Answer (score 1):

На вскидку можно так сделать

```js
// исходный SVG
let s = `<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="-10 -10 220 220" style="padding : 10px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g id="svgGroup" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="9pt" stroke="green" stroke-width="0.5mm" fill="none" style="stroke:green;stroke-width:0.5mm;fill:none"><g id="0"><g id="trapeze"><line id="line1" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line1&quot;]" x1="0" y1="200" x2="200" y2="200" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></line><line id="line2" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line2&quot;]" x1="200" y1="200" x2="175" y2="0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></line><line id="line3" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line3&quot;]" x1="175" y1="0" x2="25" y2="0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></line><line id="line4" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line4&quot;]" x1="25" y1="0" x2="0" y2="200" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></line></g></g></g></svg>`;

// меняем двойные кавычки на одинарные, конвертируем эту строку в base64 и в 
// начало строки дописываем что это закодированная определённым образом строка
let data_image = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(s.replace(/\"/g, `'`));
img.src = data_image;
```

```html
<img src="" id="img">
```

Answer (score 1):

Альтернативный вариант (ссылка в вопросе):

```js
// Cериализация в Xml svg элемента
let svg = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.getElementById('svg'));

// Строка в base64
let svg_base64 = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(svg);

console.log(svg_base64);
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="400" height="400" viewBox="-10 -10 220 220" style="padding : 10px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g id="svgGroup" stroke-linecap="round" fill-rule="evenodd" font-size="9pt" stroke="green" stroke-width="0.5mm" fill="none" style="stroke:green;stroke-width:0.5mm;fill:none"><g id="0"><g id="trapeze"><line id="line1" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line1&quot;]" x1="0" y1="200" x2="200" y2="200" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></line><line id="line2" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line2&quot;]" x1="200" y1="200" x2="175" y2="0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></line><line id="line3" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line3&quot;]" x1="175" y1="0" x2="25" y2="0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></line><line id="line4" data-route="[&quot;models&quot;,&quot;trapeze&quot;,&quot;paths&quot;,&quot;line4&quot;]" x1="25" y1="0" x2="0" y2="200" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"></line></g></g></g></svg>
```